# Recursion and Observable RxJs

Tags: javascript, recursion, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I am performing pagination inside and Observable stream.
The pagination is implemented with a cursor and a total count using recursion.

I am able to emit the every page using the following code `observer.next(searches);`, by the way I would like to use just observable and no promises but I cannot express recursion using RxJs operators.

Any suggestions?

```js
    const search = id =>
      new Observable(observer => { recursePages(id, observer) })

    const recursePages = (id, observer, processed, searchAfter) => {
      httpService.post(
        "http://service.com/search",
        {
          size: 50,
          ...searchAfter ? { search_after: searchAfter } : null,
          id,
        })
        .toPromise() // httpService.post returns an Observable<AxiosResponse>
        .then(res => {
          const body = res.data;
          const searches = body.data.hits.map(search => ({ data: search.data, cursor: search.id }));
          observer.next(searches);
          const totalProcessed = processed + searches.length;
          if (totalProcessed < body.data.total) {
            return recursePages(id, observer, totalProcessed, searches[searches.length - 1].cursor);
          }
          observer.complete();
        })
    }

    // General Observer
    incomingMessages.pipe(
        flatMap(msg => search(JSON.parse(msg.content.toString()))),
        concatAll(),
    ).subscribe(console.log),
```

Comment: I am not really familiar with RxJS, but can `take` be used for this? https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take

Comment: is the idea here to emit pages one at a time? or to emit them all at once?

Comment: @Ben `take` is used to take only a given number of values from the source observable like 
```
of(1,2,3,4,5).pipe(take(3)).subscribe(console.log) // output 1 2 3
```

Comment: @bryan60 The idea is to emit pages one at a time this in order to process them one by one

Comment: is that required from the source here or can you just transform the resulting pages array to stream with `switchMap(p => from(p))` after the fact?

Comment: @bryan60 What do you mean? Emitting 1 page at a time is a requirement for performance reasons, I need to process chunk by chunk `switchMap` can be used instead of the `flatMap` on the general observable but I don't get how using it to stream pages could help :/

Comment: you're not making much sense here. an array can be transformed into a stream with `from()`. and it's not clear what the importance of `switchMap` is to this issue.  The main reason to want to emit pages individually would be to display earlier pages before the later pages are loaded.

Comment: `The main reason to want to emit pages individually would be to display earlier pages before the later pages are loaded`

This is exactly what I am doing. I don't want to wait for all the pages to be loaded before starting to show them


`an array can be transformed into a stream with from()`
Ok so I can do `switch(p => from(p))` instead of `concatAll()` which is probably wrong in this case

Comment: Check out the expand operator. You can supply a recursive function that returns an observable https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these methods will recursively gather all the pages and emit them in an array. the pages can then be streamed with from as shown:

```
// break this out to clean up functions
const performSearch = (id, searchAfter?) => {
  return httpService.post(
    "http://service.com/search",
    {
      size: 50,
      ...searchAfter ? { search_after: searchAfter } : null,
      id,
    });
}

// main recursion
const _search = (id, processed, searchAfter?) => {
  return performSearch(id, searchAfter).pipe( // get page
    switchMap(res => {
      const body = res.data;
      const searches = body.data.hits.map(search => ({ data: search.data, cursor: search.id }));
      const totalProcessed = processed + searches.length;
      if (totalProcessed < body.total) {
        // if not done, recurse and get next page
        return _search(id, totalProcessed, searches[searches.length - 1].cursor).pipe(
          // attach recursed pages
          map(nextPages => [searches].concat(nextPages)
        );
      }
      // if we're done just return the page
      return of([searches]);
    })
  )
}

// entry point
// switch into from to emit pages one by one
const search = id => _search(id, 0).pipe(switchMap(pages => from(pages))
```

if what you really need is all of the pages to emit one by one before they're all fetched, for instance so you can show page 1 as soon as it's available rather than wait on page 2+, then that can be done with some tweaking. let me know.

EDIT: this method will emit one by one

```
const _search = (id, processed, searchAfter?) => {
  return performSearch(id, searchAfter).pipe( // get page
    switchMap(res => {
      const body = res.data;
      const searches = body.data.hits.map(search => ({ data: search.data, cursor: search.id }));
      const totalProcessed = processed + searches.length;
      if (totalProcessed < body.total) {
        // if not done, concat current page with recursive call for next page
        return concat(
          of(searches),
          _search(id, totalProcessed, searches[searches.length - 1].cursor)
        );
      }
      // if we're done just return the page
      return of(searches);
    })
  )
}
const search = id => _search(id, 0)
```

you end up with an observable structure like:

```
concat(
  post$(page1),
  concat(
    post$(page2),
    concat(
      post$(page3),
      post$(page4)
    )
  )
)
```

and since nested `concat()` operations reduce to a flattened structure, this structure would reduce to:

```
concat(post$(page1), post$(page2), post$(page3), post$(page4))
```

which is what you're after and the requests run sequentially.

it also seems like expand might do the trick as per @NickL 's comment, soemthing like:

```
search = (id) => {
  let totalProcessed = 0;
  return performSearch(id).pipe(
    expand(res => {
      const body = res.data;
      const searches = body.data.hits.map(search => ({ data: search.data, cursor: search.id }));
      totalProcessed += searches.length;
      if (totalProcessed < body.data.total) {
        // not done, keep expanding
        return performSearch(id, searches[searches.length - 1].cursor);
      }
      return EMPTY; // break with EMPTY
    })
  )
}
```

though I've never used expand before and this is based off some very limited testing of it, but I am pretty certain this works.

both of these methods could use the reduce (or scan) operator to gather results if you ever wanted:

```
search(id).pipe(reduce((all, page) => all.concat(page), []))
```

Comment: Thank you this code is pretty clear to me it fetches all the pages and then emits them all at once `.pipe(switchMap(pages => from(pages))` is converting them to a stream.

What I really need (as I commented before) is to emit one page at a time.

Comment: yea i posted my answer prior to your comment, i posted the tweak to make it work one page emission at a time

Comment: Thank you the `concat`  approach is actually what I need also it seems really clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is my used solution combining the  `expand` and `reduce` operator

```
searchUsers(cursor?: string) {
return from(
  this.slackService.app.client.users.list({
    token: this.configService.get('SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'),
    limit: 1,
    ...(cursor && { cursor }),
  }),
 );
}
```

Usage

```
.......
this.searchUsers()
  .pipe(
    expand((res) => {
      if (!!res.response_metadata.next_cursor) {
        return this.searchUsers(res.response_metadata.next_cursor);
      }
      return EMPTY;
    }),
    reduce((acc, val) => {
      return [...acc, ...val.members];
    }, []),
  )
  .subscribe((users) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
  });
....
```